# Best practices for defining fields only relevant in subclasses in Python

Tags: python, oop

If I have a variable that is only used in a subclass, should I assign None to it in the superclass?

This is minimum example, there other subclasses where ‘number’ is different but the ‘show’ method is still relevant.

```
class A:
    def show(self):
        print(self.number)

class C(A):
    number = 5

c = C()
c.show()
```

Should I define `number=None` in A?

I’m asking because PyCharm keeps showing warnings about this, but I’m not sure filling the superclass with None’s is a good idea.

Comment: No; child classes are free to add additional attributes (both class and instance) that are not part of the parent's definition. Whatever problem you are having, it's not because `A.number` is not defined.

Comment: "PyCharm keeps showing warnings about this, " what warnings? PyCharm produces no warnings with the above. Are you *using* `number` in `A`?

Comment: This is the purpose of an Abstract Base Class. Use [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

Comment: Sorry, was missing the method, @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: If you use a field in a parent class. It isn't "only relevant in the subclass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` defines a method that requires a particular attribute, `A` should also be responsible for ensuring that attribute exists. (The *value* of the attribute does not matter, but don't use `None` as an arbitrary placeholder;  if `A` doesn't have a good default value, require one be provided to `A.__init__`.)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.number = n

    def show(self):
        print(self.number)


class C(A):
    pass


c = C(5)
c.show()
```

If `number` really must be a class attribute, consider using `__init_subclass__` to set its value. (While `A.number` is not defined, this at least forces any subclass to define it.)

```
class A:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, number):
        cls.number = number

    def show(self):
        print(self.number)


class B(A, number=5):
    pass
```